# Multiplication in MySQL query (Joomla, php)

Tags: mysql, joomla2.5

I use this piece of code to display data from my database on my (joomla 2.5) web.

```
$query
    ->select($db->quoteName(array('Code', 'Name', 'Price', $username)))
    ->from($db->quoteName('mytable'))
    ->where($db->quoteName($username)." != ".$db->quote('0'));
```

$username is used to display quantity ordered by the client. So there are 4 columns. I want to add 5th column "Total" where there will be the multiplication - "Price" * "$username".

Tried to do it something like:

```
$query
    ->select(array('Code', 'Name', 'Price', $username, 'Price' * $username as 'Total'))
    ->from($db->quoteName('mytable'))
    ->where($db->quoteName($username)." != ".$db->quote('0'));
```

But for a reason it doesn't work (blank page).  What am I missing?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: price * username !?!?!

Comment: $username is used to display quantity ordered by the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a syntax error. Should be :

```
 ->select(array('Code', 'Name', 'Price', $username, "Price * $username as Total"))
```

Also the following line doesnt make any sense, should be checked in php as `$username` is a php variable:

```
->where($db->quoteName($username)." != ".$db->quote('0'));
```

Comment: Also can't find way to get SUM of newly created column Total... Can I do it in the same query? @Frank Conry Thanks in advance

Comment: you want to sum all the `Total` values? you'll need to `GROUP BY` and do it in a different query. It might be easier for you to do it in the application code (i.e. use php to do it)

Comment: Thanks again. I'll do it using php.